# Setting up a system of equations for solution

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, programming, core-language, gui-construction

There are two lists as follows:

```
Vars = 
  {{(x1)Cos[x2], Sin[x2], 0, (x3) (Sin[x2])}, {(Cos[x2]) (Sin[x4]), 
    (x3)Cos[x4], 1, x1}};
Const = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 2}};
```

Using `Vars` and `Const`, I want to make a system of equations like :

```
SysEqu = 
  {(x1)Cos[x2]==1, Sin[x2]==0, 0==0, (x3) (Sin[x2])==1,
   (Cos[x2])(Sin[x4])==0, (x3)Cos[x4]==1, 1==1, x1==2}
```

Then a UI asks about the `VARIABLES` to be solved and finally :

```
sol1 = NSolve[SysEqu, VARIABLES];
```

I know that `NSolve` generally may have some problems to give exact answers for any kind of equation. Other approaches could be acceptable instead of `NSolve[]`.

**Could you please help me with this code?!**

---

**P.S.**

To setup my equations, I used this code:

```
SetEqual = MapThread[Set, {Vars, Const}, 2];
```

However, some errors appear that two of them are :

> Tag Times in x2 Sin[x2] is Protected.
>   Cannot assign to raw object 1.

Comment: 1 isn't a variable, so naturally it cannot be assigned anything.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the Set.
Set means you're assigning something to a variable (=), x2 Sin[x2] is not a variable.
Try Equal[] instead, this is equivalent to ==.

```
Vars = {{(x1) Cos[x2], Sin[x2], 
    0, (x3) (Sin[x2])}, {(Cos[x2]) (Sin[x4]), (x3) Cos[x4], 1, x1}};
Const = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 2}};
MapThread[Equal, {Vars, Const}, 2]
```

yields the output:

```
{{x1 Cos[x2] == 1, Sin[x2] == 0, True, 
  x3 Sin[x2] == 1}, {Cos[x2] Sin[x4] == 0, x3 Cos[x4] == 1, True, 
  x1 == 2}}
```

The trues show up because you're asking 0==0 and 1==1.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. However, my major problem is still unsolved; a GUI that solve the `sol1` .

Comment: @Shellp Your request for a UI is pretty broad.  One problem is that you have six equations in four unknowns.  `NSolve[SysEqu]` "works" as it should, but there are no solutions.

Comment: @Shellp
I'm afraid that this system doesn't have solutions, you're asking:
$\sin{x_{2}}==0, x_{3}\sin{x_{2}} == 1$
This means that $x_{2}=k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}$, and $x_{2}\ne k\pi$ at the same time.